# Download files(Electron)

Tags: javascript, node.js, download, electron

I need to download files through the Electron app. Files are voluminous, weigh about 2.5-3GB. How can I implement a file download so that the download process can be paused and continued later?

Technologies that I use (Electron, Node.JS, Vue.JS latest versions). Perhaps there are some modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should checkout  [Node Download Helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-downloader-helper)

It's a node library that has an easy API for pausing and resuming downloads, rather than building your own from scratch.

[image: Here are some of its methods]